# Sending back hundreds of rows from a node and express REST API

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, rest, express

I'm working on a RESTful API using node and express (with a MySQL database).
I have a table of products, and a page on my front end which is supposed to display those products. The problem is, there's hundreds (sometimes thousands) of them, I can't just send all of them back in a response.
What is the best way (in terms of performance and speed) for transferring all those rows back to the client?
I thought of streaming the data so that the client starts displaying them while the streaming is still happening. But I have no idea on how to do that, or whether that's the best way.

Comment: You can use ajax and some parameters specifying the number of item to be fetched and from where to where, and load that data from server.

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh
Actually, I need all of them to be loaded, not only a range. I know that looks a nonsense, but that's a must.

Comment: Then you can send all the data at once,  what is the problem then?

Comment: When I have thousands of items? Of course it is

Comment: Can you give code so that we can figure out

Comment: You mentioned 'products' which I immediately assume it's something similar to e-commerce. How do they do it in e-commerce? By pages? Load when you click 'load more'? or load when you scroll down?

Comment: I'm unimpressed with REST.  Can you use AJAX or something based on that?